# How to store struct data in an array in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, assign

I have this program for school it gets data about a student, does a few calculations and stores the data in a struct which is returned by the input function.

Right now I've only got it working for one student, but I need to be able to store and output data for more than one student.

Comment: You might server yourself better by breaking this down to code which focuses specifically on the problem. It's not entirely clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"Right now I've only got it working for one student, but I need to be able to store and output data for multiple students."*

Use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

```
int n; //No. of student

std::vector<studentType> vec;
studentType s;

for(size_t i =0; i<n ;++i)
{
  s = input();
  vec.push_back(s);
}
```

And then you can access

`vec[i].studentID ; // etc, for ith student`

On another note, `void main` is not legal C++, use `int main`